# Self contained seeding of RNG in a function closure

Tags: r, random, closures, random-seed

Is there a way to set a 'localised' seed so that usage of the random number generator within a closure only depends on this seed?

For example

```
tmp_fn_test_seed <- function(seed) {
    
    set.seed(seed)
    
    function() {
        runif(1)
    }
}
```

The following sequence does not produce the same result:

```
tmp_fn_test_seed_1 <-
    tmp_fn_test_seed(1000)
tmp_fn_test_seed_2 <- 
    tmp_fn_test_seed(1000)

tmp_fn_test_seed_1()
tmp_fn_test_seed_2()
```

Instead, I obtain:

```
> tmp_fn_test_seed_1()
[1] 0.3278787
> tmp_fn_test_seed_2()
[1] 0.7588465
```

Comment: Maybe the [withr::with_seed](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/withr/versions/2.5.0/topics/with_seed) function can help

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this work for you?

```
tmp_fn_test_seed <- function(seed) {
  function() {
    old.seed <- .Random.seed
    on.exit(.GlobalEnv$.Random.seed <- old.seed)
    set.seed(seed)
    runif(1)
  }
}

tmp_fn_test_seed_1 <-
  tmp_fn_test_seed(1000)
tmp_fn_test_seed_2 <- 
  tmp_fn_test_seed(1000)

r1 <- .Random.seed
tmp_fn_test_seed_1()
#[1] 0.3278787
r2 <- .Random.seed
tmp_fn_test_seed_2()
#[1] 0.3278787
r3 <- .Random.seed

#"global" RNG state doesn't change 
all.equal(r1, r2)
all.equal(r1, r3)
```

Comment: See [this page](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2017/11/withr-2.1.0/) for a discussion of `withr` functions vs `on.exit` et al.

Comment: `withr` looks good. I will have to read up more on it. I upvoted this answer too.